# Подставить в разных местах html страницы значения из HashMap при помощи Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Мне надо сформировать html-страницу и заполнить некоторые поля значениями из HashMap с примерно таком содержанием:

```
{
    "invoiceNumber": "111",
    "claimText": "xxx",
    "requestedSum": 0
}
```

Для шаблонизации я использую движок `thymeleaf`. Как при помощи thymeleaf подставить значение из хэш-мапы в строку вида  `Претензия № {claimNumber} принята в обработку`?

Мне не нужно итерировать по всей мапе, поэтому `th:each` мне, наверное, не подходит. Мне нужно в разных частях страницы подставить разные значения из мапы.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: ${map.get('key')} ?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, а что такое map в этом коде? Если у меня на джаве мапа называется content, как мне связать ее с выражениями в шаблоне?

Comment: Передать объект в модель и использовать его с любым удобным именем. У вас какой-то другой способ?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, я при помощи thymeleaf генерирую емейл. Модели нет.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9qbfFS3A И как вы его создаете? Привидите пример

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, создаю несложно:  return templateEngine.process("sendErrors", ctx); Здесь sendErrors.html - это шаблон для thymeleaf, в которых надо подставить значения. С sendErrors все просто: там достаточно итерировать по мапе. Теперь мне надо формировать письмо иначе. Использую JavaMailSender и MimeMessagePreparator